# angularFire issue with firebaseArray.$add

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in angular so i have a problem using angularfire. 
When I use firebaseArray.$add my app just stop .
this is my controller -

```
  .controller('firebaseController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$q', "$firebaseObject", function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $q, $firebaseObject) {
    var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCgEikPPj0Ep9toUslv0iTfk53Thr-z_Fc",
        authDomain: "angularapp-80352.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://angularapp-80352.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "angularapp-80352.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "632299129047"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    const usersRef = rootRef.child('users');
    $scope.users = $firebaseArray(usersRef);
    console.log($firebaseArray(usersRef));
    console.log($scope.users);



   $scope.addUser = function (newUser) {
        $scope.users.$add(newUser).then(function(ref) {
            console.log(ref)
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
}]);
```

And when i hit addUser function the app just die

Comment: Is there any errors showing up in the developer console? Does anything happen in the network tab (in the developer tools) after you hit addUser?

Comment: No , no errors in the console and data is create in firebase properly.The only problem is that my app just die and i have to restart the browser too.

Comment: It seems that some endless loopstart